# The smoothness of a real-valued function on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

As per 'Introduction to smooth manifolds' by 'Luring W.Tu', a real valued function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is $C^{\infty}$ if there exists a coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$ on $M$ such that $f\circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth.

There are many ambiguities about the definition to me:

- Does the definition state that the chart $(U,\phi)$ lies in some atlas on $M$, or for every atlas on $M$ there exists a chart $(U,\phi)$ such that $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth?
- As an exercise in many books, if $f$ is smooth on $M$ then $f\circ \psi^{-1}:\psi(V)\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth for every chart $(V,\psi)$ on $M$. If the author in the definition of the smoothness means that there exists a single chart $(U,\phi)$ in some atlas on $M$, then it is impossible to prove such a result because the compatibility of charts in different atlases is not guaranteed.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a manifold is a set endowed with a maximal atlas, so that you will never have to consider multiple atlases for a manifold and none of the problems you pointed out exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had this point of view as well.

Answer (score 0):

As C.Falcon said, a smooth manifold is a pair $(M, A)$ where M is a manifold and A is a maximal atlas (also called differentiable structure). In Tu's book whenever he mentions an atlas and chart (since chapter 6), he means an atlas or chart contained in this differentiable structure; removing the ambiguity.